What are reliable strategies to derive solutions to bi-variate functional equations?
I tried looking at youtube, google, chatgpt, gemini, etc, but surprisingly, there's really not a concise guide, nor a user-friendly and thorough guide that I've found, which accurately tells you reliable strategies for solving functional equations.
As an exercise I set up for myself, I want to solve the equation
$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y).$
Now, right off the bat, you can tell this should be satisfied by the logarithm function.
But, I'm not here to guess, I'm here to prove. So, from scratch, without knowing in advance that the solution is $f(x) = c\log(x),$ how can I go through the process of deriving what $f(x)$ is and then proving that it's the only class of functions satisfying this equation?
I tried plugging in special values, I tried taking derivatives, but my strategies only led to contradictory results, namely that $f(x)$ is constant, which is definitely not the only solution.

Generally, there's no general solution to every bivariate functional equation - that's not quite surprising. About your question, you could look up Cauchy's functional equation, i.e. $f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)$. The solution depends on the expected domain and codomain of function f. If we look about solutions over rational field, then by elementary algebra, $f$ is linear, i.e $f(qx)=qx$. About the real field, there does exist non-linear solutions which is quite complicated. If we assume $f$ is continuous, then the solution of
$f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)$ (1)
is $f(x)=cx$. Proof:
$\forall y\in \mathbb{R}$, choose a sequence of rational numbers $\{ r_n \}$ s.t.
$\lim\limits_{x\to \inf}r_n = y$. Then
$f(y) = \lim\limits_{x\to \inf}f(r_n)$=$\lim\limits_{x\to \inf}r_nf(1)=f(1)y=cy$ for some real $c$.
Conclusively,
1.The continuous real solution of (1) is $f(x)=cx$.
2.By taking $ln$ on both sides of $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ you turn it to (1).
3.By taking $x=e^X, y=e^y$ and suitable substitution of f you turn $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ to (1).
4.By taking $ln$ on both sides of $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ you turn it to (3).
